# Configuring Gradle for iosched 2013 source from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, building

Android developer noobie here.

I got the latest iosched 2013 source and resolved most of the issues and edited the Gradle file accordingly (at least I think I am on the right track).

I can now launch the app in an AVD. Mostly resolved by:

1. Running the SDK Manager and including the libraries I figured out
2. Editing the Gradle file as below.

When I go to `Build > Clean Project`, it says `Gradle invocation completeed succesfully`

But the following lines are underlined from within Android Studio:

```
compile 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'

exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-plus:+'
```

Gradle Source:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:+' // underlined from dashclock:dashclock-api:+ 
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+' // underlined from gson:gson:2.+'
        compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.+') {
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'shared'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' // underlined from httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
            exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
        }
        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.+'
        compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-plus:+' // underlined from apis:google-api-services-plus:+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }
    }
```

Help would be most appreciated.

Thank-you!

---

**EDIT**

Added screenshots of what I mean

[image: gson]

[image: apis]
[image: dashlock]

[image: httpcomponents]

Comment: `But the following lines are underlined from within Android Studio`. What does it say? Are you able to build an run the application?

Comment: Hi @NiekHaarman. Just updated what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those *warnings* (not errors) are totally fine. In fact, I'd recommend you turning this warning off, as 90% of the time it is a false positive.

To turn off the warning, go to `File -> Settings -> Inspections`, and search for 'Spelling'. Untick the results, and click `Ok`. The warnings will disappear.

---

Bottom line: If there are no other *errors*, you should be able to build an run the application. These warnings should not prevent that.

Comment: Ok, got it. How would I then eliminate these warnings? Is there a way of resolving them by using Gradle? I assume its because the namespaces/libraries do not exist. Is there some resource that outline how to update or fix such references/dependencies?

Comment: It has totally nothing to do with that, that's why I'm always turning them off. It basically means that the underlying words do not exist in an English dictionary. The dependencies are just fine.